# Fragmentactivity and onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, oncreate

I've got a problem with fragmentactivity and onCreate method. My classes looks like this:

```
public abstract class B extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnKeyListener
{}

public class A extends B

{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // stuff
    }
}
```

OnCreate in class A is not called. I created layout from another after click and onCreate is in second layout. I don't know where is the problem.

EDIT:
leandrocastelli - i started new layout simply by creating object new A(getActivity()) not by intend.
Arash - you have right. I've to start new Activity. And now startActivity throws nullpointer :/
blackbelt - it was create like above and now i've switch to startActivity.

Comment: *OnCreate in class A is not called*, are you sure you are starting A?

Comment: I didn't understand this part " I create layout from another after click and onCreate is in second layout". Could you explain it better?

Comment: Edit your question and give some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend A class from `FragmentActivity` so your A class which is a `FragmentActivity` first should be called someway by startActivity,if you didn't do that so your subclass's onCreate would never get called

Comment: I've checked my code and that was a problem. I've got one main activity and wanted show calendar on fragmentactivity. Starting new activity by intend did the trick :) Thanks all for help :) Happy coding!